# Using armadillo linalg library with objective C++ gives compile time errors

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++, armadillo

I'm trying to integrate a C++ library that uses the C++ armadillo library with Swift by wrapping in Objective-C++. To do this I went through the general process of including the correct header and library search paths and setting the right linker arguments but as soon as I include the armadillo library in any `.mm` file I get a series of compile arguments, most of which are

`Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers`

`'T' does not refer to a value`

`Expected unqualified-id`

Most errors seem to be located near template types.

Edit: After some exploring it seems that all the issues stem from a function named "check". There seems to be more than one of these functions so I'm unsure of the issue. Some times the function is called as a method, i.e. `promote_type<eT1,eT2>::check();` and sometimes its called on its own, i.e. `template<typename X> static yes& check(typename X::Mat_fixed_type*);`
All of the errors point to functions that call `check` in some capacity so I assume thats the root of the issue, but I don't see how this has anything to do with the fact that I'm integrating with objective C++ (the errors don't pop up in a regular c++ project).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually very simple and involves fixing a naming issue. Just add `__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0` to your preprocessor macros.